# Tab doesn't select autocomplete option in typeahead component

Tags: reactjs, typeahead.js, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using the `react-bootstrap-typeahead` component and I'm having trouble figuring out what's causing the component from loosing the `tab` function to select autocomplete. If I use `onInputChange`, tab to select stops working. This appears to be affected by `onInputChange` updating the `name` field.

Is this the way the component is supposed to work or have I implemented this incorrectly. User experience isn't great.

```
<Typeahead
  onChange={(suppliersSelected) => {
    if (suppliersSelected.length === 1) {
      handleInputChange({
        supplier: {
          ...suppliersSelected[0]
        }
      });
    }
  }}
  labelKey="name"
  options={suppliers}
  selected={[
    {
      name
    }
  ]}
  id="name"
  placeholder="Supplier name"
  onInputChange={(text) => {
    handleInputChange({
      supplier: {
        name: text
      }
    });
  }}
/>
```

Comment: What is `handleInputChange`, and why are you using it inside `onChange`?

Comment: `handleInputChange` updates the state within the parent component.

Comment: can you post the code for `handleInputChange` as well as the shape of the objects in `suppliers` being passed to `options`?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question. The problem appears to be related to `selected` by removing this the problem described disappears.

Comment: Removing the `selected` prop means the typeahead is uncontrolled and selections are controlled internally by the component rather than via external props. That's a perfectly acceptable way to handle things, just note that the original issue is due to the `selected` value being updated incorrectly in your `onChange` handler.

Comment: @ericgio Yes. I've had to go back and look at this again. Removing `selected` caused the `prop` problem you described. Can you explain/show me what I'm doing wrong with onChange?